# C++ Error when declare Get Method const

Tags: c++, constants

problem with const in C++...

`MyVektor[i].getName().getFirstName()` generates error: (see code below)

```
Error 1 error C2662: 'Name::getFirstName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Name' to 'Name &' c:\users\betula\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\c++laboration_2\c++laboration_2\person_test.cpp   215 1   C++Laboration_2
```

and

```
3   IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
            object type is: const Name  c:\Users\Betula\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++Laboration_2\C++Laboration_2\Person_Test.cpp   215 17  C++Laboration_2
```

Vector and Method call from `main` in `PersonTest`...

```
vector<Person> MyPersons;

ShowPerson(MyVektor);
```

Method:

```
void ShowPerson(vector<Person> &MyVektor)
{
cout << endl << " List of people: " << endl << endl;

for( size_t i = 0; i < MyVektor.size(); i++)
{
cout << " " + MyVektor[i].getName().getFirstName() + " " + MyVektor[i].getName().getLastName() << endl;

    //cout << " " + MyVektor[i].getAddress() + " " + MyVektor[i].getAddress()+ " " +     MyVektor[i].getAddress() << endl;

    cout <<" Social security number: " + MyVektor[i].getPersNr() << endl;

    cout <<" Shoe size: " + to_string(MyVektor[i].getSkoNr()) << endl << endl;  
    }
}
```

all Getmethods are declare const i there class Person & Name

```
const Name Person::getName()
{
return my_name;
}

const string Name::getFirstName()
{
return firstName;
}
```

if i remove const declare in Class Person & Name everything works...

Any suggestions for a beginner...

/ Nimos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `const Name Person::getName()` with `Name Person::getName() const` etc. to make the functions constant as opposed to the return variable.